# Can't find the JMeter html generated report

Tags: jmeter

I have run my test plan in non GUI mode, it run successfully , but i can't find the html report in the directory i specified. Only the csv file result was there.

```
C:\Users\SamsonOluwashola\Documents\apache-jmeter-5.0\bin>jmeter -n -t C:\Users\SamsonOluwashola\Documents\apache-jmeter-5.0\bin\creditLimitOp1.jmx -l C:\Users\SamsonOluwashola\Documents\apache-jmeter-5.0\bin\reportHTML\ccrditlimit.csv -e -o C:\Users\SamsonOluwashola\Documents\apache-jmeter-5.0\bin\reportHTML\creditLimit.html
Creating summariser <summary>
Created the tree successfully using C:\Users\SamsonOluwashola\Documents\apache-jmeter-5.0\bin\creditLimitOp1.jmx
Starting the test @ Thu Oct 18 09:34:37 BST 2018 (1539851677846)
Waiting for possible Shutdown/StopTestNow/Heapdump message on port 4445
summary +    200 in 00:00:22 =    9.0/s Avg:  2019 Min:     0 Max:  5627 Err:     0 (0.00%) Active: 33 Started: 41 Finished: 8
summary +    203 in 00:00:16 =   12.5/s Avg:  2054 Min:     0 Max:  6348 Err:     0 (0.00%) Active: 0 Started: 41 Finished: 41
summary =    403 in 00:00:38 =   10.5/s Avg:  2036 Min:     0 Max:  6348 Err:     0 (0.00%)
Tidying up ...    @ Thu Oct 18 09:35:16 BST 2018 (1539851716518)
... end of run
```

Answer (score 1):

[JMeter Dashboard's -o parameter](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/generating-dashboard.html#report_after_load_test) gets a **folder** value and not file (HTML).

> jmeter -n -t test JMX file -l test log file -e -o Path to **output folder**

Change execution to `.. -o C:\Users\SamsonOluwashola\Documents\apache-jmeter-5.0\bin\reportHTML`

Comment: just done that but its only the .csv result in the folder

Comment: @OLATUNBOSUNOLUWASHOLA can you try with different folder as `C:\Users\SamsonOluwashola\Documents\apache-jmeter-5.0\bin\NewDir`

Comment: .....-l C:\Users\Documents\apache-jmeter-5.0\bin\CSVreport\ccrditlimit.csv -e -o C:\Users\Documents\apache-jmeter-5.0\bin\GraphicalReport                                    just done this, only the CSVreport folder got created after test run. the GraphicalReport folder did not get created.

Answer (score 1):

JMeter **cannot generate HTML Report in a non-empty folder**, consider storing .jtl file in one place and the dashboard in another. You can [copy](https://www.windows-commandline.com/windows-copy-command-syntax-examples/) the .jtl file to report folder once dashboard generation is completed.

Also consider adding [`-f` argument to your command line](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#options) so JMeter could overwrite the results file if it exists (it might be another cause for your problem)

The final command line would be something like:

```
jmeter -n -t -f C:\Users\Documents\apache-jmeter-5.0\bin\creditLimitOp1.jmx -l C:\Users\Documents\apache-jmeter-5.0\bin\crdlimit.csv -e -o C:\Users\Documents\apache-jmeter-5.0\bin\report && copy C:\Users\Documents\apache-jmeter-5.0\bin\crdlimit.csv C:\Users\Documents\apache-jmeter-5.0\bin\report
```

Another way of viewing your test result in a fancy HTML version is using [BM.Sense](https://sense.blazemeter.com/) service